# How would you translate a proverb: "May the bridges I've burnt light my way."

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I have once again a question to solve. Thank you in advance!

How would you translate to latin:
"May the bridges I've burnt light my way."

Light may be enlight too.

Answer (score 8):

Quite literally: *Illustrent pontes, quos combussi, mihi viam.*

That is not particularly pithy. You might want to shorten it a bit, leaving a few things implied that are explicit in English. I also think the bridges can only light you the way while they're still on fire …

So you could, for example, say:

> *Illustrent flagrantes viam pontes*

= may the burning bridges light the way (it being implied that it was you who set them on fire).

Comment: This is an even better translation considering the actual quote is supposed to be: "May the bridges I burn light the way" (aka, them needing to still be on fire, as you pointed out).